# Wicked, after delete action redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rubygems, destroy

I have used wicked gem for my form. The thing is when user uploads photo they can see at the same page as `..../steps/picture`. At Picture page user can destroy the picture. When user clicks I would like them to redirect_to steps/picture page but whatever I tried I get error on that. Boat and Picture associated but not nested routes.

here is my picture controller `#destroy` action;

def destroy

```
@picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])
if @picture.destroy
 ######SOMETHING GOES HERE#########
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed picture."
else
  render json: { message: @picture.errors.full_messages.join(',') }
end
```

end

`#boat_steps` controller;

```
class BoatStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard


    before_action :logged_in_user
    steps :model, :pricing, :description, :features, :picture

    def show
        @boat = current_user.boats.last
    case step
    when :picture
        @picture = @boat.pictures.new
        @pictures = @boat.pictures.all
    end
        render_wizard

    end

    def update
        @boat = current_user.boats.last
        @boat.update(boat_params)
        case step
    when :picture
        @picture.update(picture_params)

    end

        render_wizard @boat


    end


private

    def finish_wizard_path
        new_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture)
    end



    def boat_params
      params.require(:boat).permit(......)
    end

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(......)
    end


end
```

EDIT 1:

```
>rake routes
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
           update_years GET    /boats/update_years(.:format)               boats#update_years
          update_models GET    /boats/update_models(.:format)              boats#update_models
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
          boat_pictures GET    /boats/:boat_id/pictures(.:format)          pictures#index
                        POST   /boats/:boat_id/pictures(.:format)          pictures#create
       new_boat_picture GET    /boats/:boat_id/pictures/new(.:format)      pictures#new
      edit_boat_picture GET    /boats/:boat_id/pictures/:id/edit(.:format) pictures#edit
           boat_picture GET    /boats/:boat_id/pictures/:id(.:format)      pictures#show
                        PATCH  /boats/:boat_id/pictures/:id(.:format)      pictures#update
                        PUT    /boats/:boat_id/pictures/:id(.:format)      pictures#update
                        DELETE /boats/:boat_id/pictures/:id(.:format)      pictures#destroy
                  boats GET    /boats(.:format)                            boats#index
                        POST   /boats(.:format)                            boats#create
               new_boat GET    /boats/new(.:format)                        boats#new
              edit_boat GET    /boats/:id/edit(.:format)                   boats#edit
                   boat GET    /boats/:id(.:format)                        boats#show
                        PATCH  /boats/:id(.:format)                        boats#update
                        PUT    /boats/:id(.:format)                        boats#update
             boat_steps GET    /boat_steps(.:format)                       boat_steps#index
                        POST   /boat_steps(.:format)                       boat_steps#create
          new_boat_step GET    /boat_steps/new(.:format)                   boat_steps#new
         edit_boat_step GET    /boat_steps/:id/edit(.:format)              boat_steps#edit
              boat_step GET    /boat_steps/:id(.:format)                   boat_steps#show
                        PATCH  /boat_steps/:id(.:format)                   boat_steps#update
                        PUT    /boat_steps/:id(.:format)                   boat_steps#update
                        DELETE /boat_steps/:id(.:format)                   boat_steps#destroy
    password_resets_new GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)              password_resets#new
   password_resets_edit GET    /password_resets/edit(.:format)             password_resets#edit
          profiles_edit GET    /profiles/edit(.:format)                    profiles#edit
           sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                     sessions#new
                   root GET    /                                           main#home
                   help GET    /help(.:format)                             main#help
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                            main#about
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                          main#contact
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                           users#new
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                            sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                            sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                           sessions#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format)     account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)                  password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)              password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)         password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)              password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)              password_resets#update
```

EDIT:

Boat steps controller

```
class BoatStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard


    before_action :logged_in_user
    steps :model, :pricing, :description, :features, :picture

    def show
        @boat = current_user.boats.last
    case step
    when :picture
        @picture = @boat.pictures.new
        @pictures = @boat.pictures.all
    end
        render_wizard

    end

    def update
        @boat = current_user.boats.last
        @boat.update(boat_params)
        case step
    when :picture
        @picture.update(picture_params)

    end

        render_wizard @boat


    end


private

    def finish_wizard_path
        new_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture)
    end



    def boat_params
      params.require(:boat).permit(:brand, :year, :model, :captained, :boat_type, :daily_price, :boat_length, :listing_tagline, :listing_description, :boat_category, :hull_material, :mast_material, :capacity, :sleeping_capacity, :private_staterooms, :fuel_type, :engine_horsepower, :fuel_capacity, :fuel_consumption, :draft)
    end

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :boat_id, :image)
    end


end
```

Comment: You will just need to use `redirect_to`.  If you have doubts, post `rake routes` in your question.

Comment: here I edited the question

Comment: What error were you getting?

Comment: I dont get any error, I just dont know how to redirect to steps/picture path

Comment: I don't see `/steps/picture` defined as a route.

Comment: sorry should be ...boat_steps/picture

Comment: Don't see that one either.  What `controller` action do you want?  For instance, if you want `boat_steps#show`, you would use `redirect_to boat_step_path`.

Comment: So when I press next button it moves like, .../boat_steps/model , .../boat_steps/pricing, .../boat_steps/pictures ... So I would like to redirect to last one again. Let me add my boat steps controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On wicked wizards there are path helpers available on views that don't show on `rake routes`.

Try `redirect_to wizard_path(:picture)`

You can find more information about wicked helpers available to views here: https://github.com/schneems/wicked#quick-reference

These helpers will be available on views rendered using `render_wizard`. Outside of the wizard, the step is passed as the `:id` of the RESTful route.
To redirect to boat_steps/show on the picture step try `redirect_to boat_step_path(id: :picture)`. The url generated should be `/boat_steps/picture`.

Comment: Throws an error ; `undefined method 'wizard_path' for #<PicturesController:0x007fbe949128c8>`

Comment: Do you think I can use those helpers outside, Because `#destroy` action is in the picture controller. Picture and Boat models are associated if relevant

Comment: @Shalafister I have edited my answer to provide more directions. I hope it helps.